# Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, support-v4

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.jar

MY SDK Tool is like this image

[image]

And my Gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lionvisionsits.kkasons"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24

        multiDexEnabled false

    }


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.3'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

can anyone help me?

After Updating to v24.2.1 i get this error in debug\AndroidMenifest.xml
[image]

Thanks & Regards
Jay

Comment: Strange issue. This library is not in the jcenter but in a local maven repo.Try to update the SDK Manager and use compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1

Comment: Thanks for reply. i tried 24.2.1 but it throws error in AndroidMenifest.xml .Let me send detail for that.

Comment: i Added screen shot...ple. look in to it @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: You can't use these attributes in the Manifest. They are added after building the apk,

Comment: Thanks man ..you are right i can not use them. Actually i had lost source code so i needed menifest so reverse engineered it and got that.

Comment: change google play service version.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do some changes in your build.gradle file inside platforms/android and need to add maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } before the jcenter() as follows:

```
allprojects { 
  repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //add this code
    jcenter() 
 } 
}
```

This is now essential for new versions of google libraries. They moved their libraries out of the android SDK to the maven repo.

Comment: Thanks Sandy..You saved my day.Moving up google before jcenter works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, i updated :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'
```

and my gradle wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

and it works

Answer (score 4):

in my case in build.gradle file I had to add and reorder the repositories, such that jcenter is the last place where entry is searched for:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral() //+ added
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //^ moved up
    jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sandy The difference is that I discover that even in case of entry already present, you should reorder them. If not stated, users cannot understand how to solve since the entryes can already be there, like in my case

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, the following steps fixed my probelm. Give it try and see if it helps:

[image]

Go to "File" -> "Project Structure...".

Select "your project" under "Modules" and click on "Dependencies" tab.

Click on the "+" sign and select "1 Library dependency".

[image]

In the new popup window, select "support-v4" and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of `buildVersionCode` or `name` required in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can better define it in app `build.gradle` file. Like below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.r"
    minSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 418
    versionName "4.4.0"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0` is different to the android studio. You can try to do like this: `File-> project structure->app->dependencies->+->Library dependency`, the select the `com.android.support:support-v4:xx.x.x`. If any problem, you can change the library to the lastest.

Answer (score 0):

try this inside in `android` block

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Or if you have `model` block then try this

```
compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i have the same issue, and now i solve it.
I have two place define "support-v4".
one:maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
because http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/ define "support-v4"
two:compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
I delete compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' in my module, then the project works.
Appear this issue may be your project have two place that  define "support-v4", so IDE don't known how to find the corrent one.

Comment: This does not sound like an answer, or?